# Putting citation on right side of the equation

Tags: equations, citing

I have written an equation in LaTeX and I need to cite the author name with date (Einstein 1915) on the right side of my equation, I tried with the margin note command but it gets split in two lines, how do I get it in one line just right-below my equation?

Comment: Please edit you post and show us an minimal example of what you have tried. In the current form, we will have to guess around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\tag` command from the `mathtools` package (useless to load `amsmath` in that case). If you don't want the parentheses, use \ tag*:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothsides]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}       

    \begin{gather}
    E = mc^{2}\tag{Einstein 1915}\\
    E = mc^{2}\tag*{Einstein 1915}
    \end{gather}

    \end{document}
```

[image]